# How does React allow the use of "<" and ">" characters without having the JS interpreter crash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't understand how the arrow characters can be used in JS without being wrapped in strings. For example:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="empty">No messages to show.</div>
    );

}
```

I understand how we can use arrows as keys in an object:

```
obj = {};
obj['<div>'] = document.createElement('div')
```

But in this instance the arrows are wrapped in a string. How does React allow these characters without crashing the JavaScript interpreter?

Comment: This is explained in the second sentence on the react site :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't parsed as JavaScript because it's inserted into a `script` tag whose `type` isn't `text/javascript`. React uses a a `script` tag whose `type` is set to `text/babel`, *not* `text/javascript`. The content within this `script` element isn't treated as JavaScript.

Here's a Stack Snippet to demonstrate this:

```html
<script type="text/example">
  This <throws> "no JavaScript% errors as it
  isn't treated ^ as JavaScript.
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  This one, however, will throw errors. Oh no!
</script>
```

The first example here is parsed as `text/example` and doesn't go through the JavaScript compiler at all. The second example is parsed as `text/javascript` and *does* therefore get treated as such:

The error we get from the above snippet is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier `js:17`

`js:17` here is the `This one, however, will throw errors. Oh no!` within our latter `script` element.:

[image: Example]

Comment: This is only done in demos though. No one is doing this in production (I hope at least).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. If you use JSX you have to use a *transpiler* to convert your code to valid JavaScript. The recommended one is [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

For more information about the transform see http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#the-transform .